# Accessory checkmarks disappear when scrolling Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I have a tableview that I can add and remove multiple checkmarks. The only issue is if I put 3 checkmarks and scroll away, when I return the checkmarks are gone. I can't find anywhere on the internet a solution that works, and I've tried several variation and still nothing.

This is my code in cellForRowAtIndex that should be holding the checkmarks in place.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"contactCell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
NSDictionary *contact = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString *firstName = contact[@"firstName"];
    nameLabel.text = [firstName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", contact[@"lastName"]]];

    UILabel *phoneNumber = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSArray *phones = contact[@"phones"];

    if ([phones count] > 0) {
        NSDictionary *phoneItem = phones[0];
        phoneNumber.text = phoneItem[@"value"];
    }

    UIImageView *cellIconView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:888];

    UIImage *image = contact[@"image"];

    cellIconView.image = (image != nil) ? image : [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley-face"];
    cellIconView.contentScaleFactor = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cellIconView.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(cellIconView.frame) / 2;




// Need to fix
if([checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}


return cell;
}
```

Here is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {



UITableViewCell* checkCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];




 if(checkCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    checkCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;




    NSMutableArray *i = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
        [i addObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];

        // Go inside pull the numbers from the users and save in an NSArray
     //   NSArray *contacts = i;

   //     self.recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        for (NSDictionary* dict in i) {

            // Grab phones
            NSDictionary *contactNumber = [dict objectForKey:@"phones"];

            for (NSDictionary* dict2 in contactNumber) {

                // Grabs the phone numbers
                NSString* value = [dict2 objectForKey:@"value"];
                int index = [self.recipients indexOfObject:value];

                [self.recipients removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                [self.selectedUsers removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                NSLog(@"The number that has a checkmark%@", value);
                NSLog(@"the array of all%@", self.recipients);
                NSLog(@"At index %lu", (unsigned long)[self.recipients indexOfObject:value]);
                // [_recipients addObject:value];
            }

        }
        // NSLog(@"Phone Numbers: %@",_recipients);
    }


}

else
{
    [self getNumber];

    NSLog(@"clicking %@", self.recipients);

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    checkedIndexPath = indexPath;


  }
 }
```

**I found The Solution:**
You must save each indexPath into an array(put this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath) and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath add the following code

```
if([self.checkedCells containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Also in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
Make sure to delete the indexPath when deselecting the row.

```
 if(checkCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    checkCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.checkedCells removeObject:indexPath];
```

I hope this helps someone. I been wrestling with this all day.

Comment: from where _checkedIndexPath comes from? are you storing this at class level?

Comment: _checkdIndexPath is just tracking the last NSIndexPath selected. Yes its and instance variable of my VC.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Also, are you expecting multiple check marks to work? Because I only see you recording one checked index path.

Comment: Update your question with the full code of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` methods. BTW - you do realize that having the single `_checkedIndexPath` only allows you to keep track of a single selection.

Comment: I added the rest of the code.

Comment: Yes I'm able to select multiple checkmarks and also remove them fine. I only get an issue when I scroll away from the checkmarks, and when I come back the checkmarks are gone, but I still have the object stored in an array.

Comment: You are only tracking the last checked row with your single `checkedIndexPath` variable.

Comment: I could create an array to store all the indexPath. But I don't know how can I use it to restore the checkmarks when I scroll back. Can you guide me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @rmaddy can you please provide an example on how you would solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Check out the solution I came up with. containsObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `checkedIndexPath` a `@property (nonatomic, strong)` and use `self.checkedIndexPath` whenever you refer to it. You're losing the reference after `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` exits. Set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and look at `checkedIndexPath`, I bet it's nil.

Comment: You're correct, I do get a nil. Why is this happening?

Comment: I told you why - you are not storing a reference to checkedIndexPath and it's going out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Check out the solution I came up with. containsObject

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Maybe you should check if the `isEqual` functionality does what you expect. You could make sure by trying:</strike>

```
if (_checkedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section &&
    _checkedIndexPath.row     == indexPath.row)
```

If you still do not get the expected result, perhaps log the values of `section` and `row` to see where it goes wrong.

Please note that if for some reason `_checkedIndexPath` is a weak variable or gets deallocated, this check will fail.

You could also check that your cells are properly dequeued before being modified and that you are returning the correct cells.

If you want to store more than one checked row, of course, you will need more than one indexPath variable (just one `_checkedIndexPath` will not do it).

Comment: The use of `isEqual:` on the `NSIndexPath` is just fine.

Comment: In view of all the other helpful hints, I find the down-vote rather harsh. I also happened to catch the actual error in my list of things to check.